# Is there a way to use test Ajax / JSON/ XML without having a database?

Tags: ajax, xml, json

I'm in the process of updating my skills, and finally decided to take up AJAX/JSON/XML (I've been using JS for ages, but never had the chance to do Ajax).

So, is there a way to test XMLhttp requests on your local machine without a server? Is there a database out there that I can link to to see results of what I'm doing?

I'd appreciate any input.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options for you: you can find a publicly available API that interests you, and work with that. There's a big catalog of them at http://www.programmableweb.com/.  Note that many public APIs will require you to register for a developer key before you can use them.

Or, you can set up a very simple server that just responds to requests with JSON or XML; sinatra is pretty easy to set up (http://www.sinatrarb.com/), as one example.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look!

Comment: I've got Wamp server installed on my machine. Can this work as well?

Comment: Absolutely, just set up an index.php or index.html file in a subfolder, and make that page just return json object.

Comment: Noted. Thank you! I'll have a tinker.